# Are there current denominations that have doctrines stating that The Lord will return at a particular date?

Tags: eschatology

With a couple extreme examples highlighted by the media in recent years, I'm curious if there are doctrinal statements that have been made citing that Christ will return on a particular date?

Comment: I've heard that Jehovah's Witnesses believe that the Second Coming has actually already occurred at a specific date in the 20th Century, but that it wasn't the major, worldwide event that mainstream Christianity expects, which is why the rest of us didn't notice.  Does anyone know enough about JW doctrine to clarify this point?

Comment: See [this](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16431/which-sects-interpret-day-and-hour-unknown-literally)

Answer (score 5):

There are almost always such groups. And since the term denomination is so ill-defined, and so broad that any group of united believers qualifies, the answer is most certainly, "yes, at any given time, there are several groups that could be called 'denominations' that have a predicted date for Christ's return".  [Invariably, they backpedal when that date passes without said event](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4255/what-doctrine-does-family-radio-have-of-the-end-of-the-world?rq=1).

To answer your specific question...  Currently, [this group](http://www.lasttrumpet.org/seven_proofs.htm), for example, predicts  Yom Kippur 2017 (September 30th 2017) as the date.

Of course, [most Christians believe what Jesus actually said, and reject the idea that the date can be predicted](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4718/what-is-the-biblical-basis-against-being-able-to-predict-the-date-of-the-end-of?rq=1).